# Unable to delete SharePoint list which contains more than 100000 items

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online, threshold, sharepoint-list, microsoft365

I have created a list under SharePoint Online that contains  100000+ items.

Now, I need to delete that list. So, I have tried to delete the list from List Settings.

It has thrown the below error message.

[image]

Can anyone help me with the same?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The error message you are seeing indicates that [the number of items in the list exceeds the list view threshold, which is 5000 items by default](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/troubleshoot/lists-and-libraries/items-exceeds-list-view-threshold). This error occurs because SharePoint Online uses the Large List Resource Throttling feature, which prohibits tasks that cause excessive server load.

To resolve this issue, you can try the following:

1.[Use indexing to improve the performance of the list](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/manage-large-lists-and-libraries-b8588dae-9387-48c2-9248-c24122f07c59).

2.Use filtering to reduce the number of items returned by the list.

3.Use folders to organize the items in the list. You'll need to configure a view that displays less than 5,000 items and make it the default view.

4.Manually delete files in List in batches.